# Adding Views to FrameLayout - Xamarin, Android, Monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How do I add views to a FrameLayout. I would like to be able to create a new View from a custom View class and add that to a FrameLayout. The custom view will have an OnDraw() method that will be associated with a specific drawable/bitmap.

I would like the ability to draw on top a picture, and I can't seem to get my layouts/views to work.

**Am I adding the ImageView to my FrameLayout correctly?**

```
protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        this.image = new ImageView (this);
        //image = FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.imageView1);
        //this.image.SetScaleType (ImageView.ScaleType.CenterInside);
        //SetContentView (this.image, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent));
        FrameLayout m_Layout = FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.frameLayout1);
        //m_Layout.AddView (image);
        SetContentView (m_Layout);

        this.path = (savedInstanceState ?? Intent.Extras).GetString ("path");
        Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName (this.path);

        Cleanup();
        DecodeBitmapAsync (path, 400, 400).ContinueWith (t => {
            image = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            image.SetImageBitmap (this.bitmap = t.Result);
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:minWidth="25px"
    p1:minHeight="25px"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/frameLayout1">
    <ImageView
        p1:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        p1:layout_width="match_parent"
        p1:layout_height="match_parent"
        p1:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding the image to the `FrameLayout`. You are close with your commented out lines but you need to set the `LayoutParameters` on the new `ImageView` you create. So something like this after you call `SetContentView(m_Layout)`.

```
this.image = new ImageView(this);
this.image.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
m_Layout.AddView(this.image);
```

Now you should be able to set the `this.image` bitmap and have it appear on the screen.

Comment: Can I continue to add more imageviews onto the layout? perhaps be able to move them and overlap them on previous imageviews? or is it going to be like laying out and android layout where they have their predefined area?

Comment: Yes, FrameLayout stacks its children on top of each other. So you can keep calling `mLayout.AddView(imageview);` for however many images you want. As for moving them you may need to have a RelativeLayout as a child of the FrameLayout and then set the ImageView LayoutParameters to wherever you wan the ImageView to go inside of the RelativeLayout.

Comment: What should I be looking to call to update the screen as I add the new layout dynamically? Should I keep calling setContentView()?

Comment: If you want to keep adding overlay images to the screen you can keep calling `m_Layout.AddView(imageview);`. This will keep stacking children on top of each other. Otherwise, calling `SetContentView()` would reset the entire layout.